# Collecting energy from 70-80 Celsius degree heat heat

Tags: current-source

I'm assembling a wireless thermostat for radiators. The module is powered with batteries.

I searched for a way to recharge the accumulator from the heat generated by the radiator but I could not find anythin.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Thermoelectric generator/Seebeck generator??

Comment: Note that you can't harvest energy from heat, you need heat (temperature) *difference*.

Comment: Look at micropelt

Answer (score 1):

Thermoelectric generators (TEG) or peltier or seebeck devices.

Aliexpress lists lots of these. I see that some are now listed as [optimised for generation](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/TEC1-27145-SP1848-TEC-Thermoelectric-Heatsink-Cooler-Peltier-Plate-Module/2174074_32800561933.html), rather than cooling.

You need heat to flow through it, and a temperature difference across it, so it needs a heatsink that is cooled by the room air (maybe colder at floor?)

The good news - cheap and capable of making heaps of current if you can keep the cold side cold.

Alternatives: Ali has little inline water powered generators that power shower leds/thermostats etc.

Comment: Maybe for your example as "listed here" you can also post the part number in the answer. In this case you can still look up the mentioned part after the aliexpress link is down.

Comment: @RemcoVink  Aliexpress. China. Part Number. Data. ROTFL

Answer (score 0):

The device to use here is named Thermoelectric generator. See [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator)
Anyway, to make it possible you would need temperature gradient. The greater it is, the higher energy can be obtained in the generator module. Please see [Seebeck_effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Seebeck_effect)

Also, consider limited heat dissipation from your heat sink.